# Does Console.WriteLine take any time in a WinForms app when no console is connected?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, console

In my Windows Forms app I use `Console.WriteLine` to spew debugging information to Visual Studio's Output window.  I prefer this to `Debug.WriteLine` because it works even for Release builds, and for speed reasons I need to do my debugging in Release mode.  But I wonder: if I leave those `Console.WriteLines` in my app and deploy it, will they affect the speed of the deployed version?  I know that Visual Studio somehow "attaches" to the app's console output to show the results of `Console.WriteLine`.  My question is, when nothing is attached in that fashion, is `Console.WriteLine` a no-op (or at least a very fast operation)?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this thread https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/428018-console-writeline-release-builds-performance-issue

Comment: @bwegs, thanks.  I hadn't considered just timing it.  Got my answer.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the [forum thread](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/428018-console-writeline-release-builds-performance-issue) linked by @bwegs, I decided to do a quick test.  A million calls to `Console.WriteLine` with the debugger attached took a long time (actually I stopped the app rather than let it run to completion).  Running the same exe from File Explorer (not attached to the debugger), the same million calls returned essentially immediately.  So, for my purposes, `Console.WriteLine` is fast enough without a console attached to leave in my application.